# MVC & ADO.NET - Where does the data access code belong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I've downloaded a few example MVC applications from Microsoft and other sources to get a feel for where everything belongs in the MVC project. But all the projects seem to have a slightly different strategy to one another (and most use EF, which I'm not).

Some make all their database calls from the controller, others from the domain model, and others have a DAL to handle this.

What's best practice when using ADO.NET? Where should the database changes/retrievals be initiated and where should the ADO.NET code be kept?

The database access code can be lengthy so it doesn't feel like it should be in the controller as that would make the controller hard to read. Should I have a DAL that handles all connections to the database and then make calls to  that from the controller?

I thought the controller was only meant to pass views around and initiate actions on the models?

Comment: Database calls shouldn't be made directly from a controller. That violates separation of concerns. It should be in a different class and possibly a different project.

Comment: @mason so if I want to save the data from my view (via viewmodel) do I post the form,  then in the controller I pass those values to my domain model and tell the domain model to save to the db?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: AFAIK, the model is the part of MVC that is in charge of the managing the data. Using n-tier on top of MVC seems too much to me. BTW, ado.net code doesn't have to be lengthy. You can reduce a lot of the code repetition by using [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) (that I wrote and is free to download from github).

Comment: @ZoharPeled See... there seems to be no consensus regarding where things belong.

Comment: @JackReilly Not true. From [ASP.NET MVC Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx) on MSDN. "Model objects are the parts of the application that implement the logic for the application's data domain. Often, model objects retrieve and store model state in a database. "